# Asp Core 5.0 Razor Page: how to preserve window.location.hash when calling RedirectToPage()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, .net-5

I have Asp Core 5.0 Razor Page with a table that represents for example Messages from database. There are several tables that are placed inside several tabs (Boostrap 4 **nav-pills**). Each record has a icon for some action that modify a message:

```
<a asp-page-handler="ModifyMessage" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Modify message"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Code-behind for that action looks something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetModifyMessageAsync(Int64 Id)
{
     var message = _context.Messages.Single(m => m.Id == Id);
     message.MessageIsRead = !message.MessageIsRead;

     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

     return RedirectToPage(); //it can be Page();
}
```

On my View is save active tab Id in **window.location.hash** when user changes active tab. Afterwards I read **window.location.hash** and restore active tab on page reload.

**window.location.hash** value is preserved between page reloads via F5 (or even Ctrl+F5) and via JavaScript:

```
$('#SomeButtonId').click(function (e) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
```

But **window.location.hash** value is cleared when page reloads via `return RedirectToPage();` (or `return Page();`).

So howto preserve **window.location.hash** when calling **RedirectToPage()**?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally ended with not using `asp-page-handler` and `asp-route-id` tags and using JavaScript/jQuery + AJAX solution:

```
<a title="Modify message"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>

<script>
var ModifyMessage= function (messageId) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '?handler=ModifyMessage',
        data: "messageId=" + messageId,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fa-edit").parent("a").click(function (e) {
        //get current message Id somehow
        var messageId= $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].children[0].innerText.trim();
        //call AJAX function           
        ModifyMessage(messageId);
        //refresh page to get all messages current state (preserves window.location.hash)
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
</script>
```

Code-behind:

```
public JsonResult OnGetModifyMessage(Int64 messageId)
{
     var message = _context.Messages.Single(m => m.Id == messageId);
     message.MessageIsRead = !message.MessageIsRead;

     _context.SaveChanges();

     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with nav tabs also. I came up with a solution that it somewhat acceptable. What you have to do is programmatically click the tab on page load.
In your Get method, pass in the active tab's id to the request:
I am not sure if you have this in an index file but if this request is in Index.cshtml.cs you would redirect to /index/id/activeTabId. Comment below so I can see how your routing is set up.

```
 OnGetModifyMessageAsync(Int64 Id,activeTabId){
   
  return RedirectToPage($"/{Id}/#{activeTabId}")
}
```

In you JS doc on page load, you get the window location and click the tab with javascript:

```
window.onload =function(){
   let loc = window.location.href;
    if (loc.includes("#")) {
        let activeTabId = refLoc.substring(refLoc.indexOf('#') + 1, refLoc.length);
        document.getElementById(activeTabId).click();
    }
}
```